# what is the best practice of Vert.x handler for checking check existence?

Tags: asynchronous, reactive-programming, future, vert.x

I am implementing a method using Vertx to check the existence of certain value in the database and use [Handler](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Handler.html) with [AsyncResult](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/AsyncResult.html).

I would like to know which one is the best practice:

**Option 1: When nothing found, Handler is with succeededFuture but with result as FALSE:**

```
public void checkExistence (..., String itemToFind, Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> resultHandler) {
    // ....
    doQuery(..., queryHandler -> {
        if (queryHandler.succeeded()) {
            List<JsonObject> results = queryHandler.result();
            boolean foundIt = false;
            for (JsonObject json: results) {
                if (json.getString("someKey").equals(itemToFind)) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(foundIt));
        } else {
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(queryHandler.cause().toString()));
        }
    });
}
```

**Option 2: When nothing found, Handler is with failedFuture:**

```
public void checkExistence (..., String itemToFind, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> resultHandler) {
    // ....
    doQuery(..., queryHandler -> {
        if (queryHandler.succeeded()) {
            List<JsonObject> results = queryHandler.result();
            boolean foundIt = false;
            for (JsonObject json: results) {
                if (json.getString("someKey").equals(itemToFind)) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // HERE IS THE DIFFERENCE!!!
            if (foundIt) {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
            } else {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture("Item " + itemToFind + " not found!"));
            }
        } else {
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(queryHandler.cause().toString()));
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Let's say I have another example, instead of checking the existence, I would like to get all the results.  Do I check the *Empty* results? Do I treat *Empty* as failure or success?

**Option 1: only output them when it's not null or empty, otherwise, fail it**

```
public void getItems(..., String itemType, Handler<AsyncResult<List<Item>>> resultHandler) {
    // ....
    doQuery(..., queryHandler -> {
        if (queryHandler.succeeded()) {
            List<Item> items = queryHandler.result();
            if (items != null && !items.empty()) {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(items));
            } else {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture("No items found!"));
            }

        } else {
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(queryHandler.cause().toString()));
        }
    });
}
```

**Option 2: output results I got, even though it could be empty or `null`**

```
public void getItems(..., String itemType, Handler<AsyncResult<List<Item>>> resultHandler) {
    // ....
    doQuery(..., queryHandler -> {
        if (queryHandler.succeeded()) {
            List<Item> items = queryHandler.result();
            resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(items));
        } else {
            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(queryHandler.cause().toString()));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st one option is better, because you can clearly say, that `checkExistence` returned `True` or `False` and completed successfully or it failed with some exception (database issue, etc.).

But lets say, you've decided to stick with 2nd option. Then, imagine you have another method:

```
void getEntity(int id, Handler<AsyncResult<Entity>> resultHandler);
```

If `entity` with provided `id` doesn't exists, will you throw exception (using `Future.failedFuture`) or return `null` (using `Future.succeededFuture`)? I think, you should throw exception to make your methods logic similar to each other. But again, is that exceptional situation?

For case with returning list of entities you can just return empty list, if there are no entities. Same goes to single entity: it's better to return `Optional<Entity>` instead of `Entity`, because in this way you avoid `NullPointerException` and don't have nullable variables in the code. What's better: `Optional<List<Entity>>` or empty `List<Entity>`, it's open question.

Answer (score 1):

Particularly if you're writing this as reusable code, then definitely go with your first option. This method is simply determining whether an item exists, and so should simply return whether it does or not. How is this particular method to know whether it's an error condition that the item doesn't exist?

Some caller might determine that it is indeed an error; it that's the case, then it will throw an appropriate exception if the Future returns with *false*. But another caller might simply need to know whether the item exists before proceeding; in that case, you'll find yourself using exception handling to compose your business logic.

Comment: Regarding the update, the answer is the same (well, strictly speaking the answer is now "go with your second option" since you switched the options around ;)). Again, the job of this method is to return as many results as exist. It doesn't have enough context to determine whether "0 results" is an error. That's up to whoever is calling it. In fact I did something similar (using vert.x and RxJava) where I am looking for one user. I return a <Single<Optional<User>>>. The Optional either is empty or contains the value is found. Error reporting is reserved for true errors (e.g. DB connectivity)